# Java application running significantly faster on Mac OS than Windows

Tags: windows, mac, cpu, performance, java

I was told to post this here, from [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45290270/java-application-running-significantly-faster-on-mac-os-than-windows).

I am trying to run a Java program which finds Poly divisible numbers. However, I have found that it is significantly slower on my Windows computer in comparison to the speed it runs at on a MacBook Pro.

Do you know any reason **why this may be and how this could be fixed?**

**Windows Specs:**

- i7 7700k @ 4.2 GHz (4 Cores, 8 threads)
- 16 GB RAM @ 3000MHz. (DDR4)
- Timings: https://gist.github.com/JosephBywater/f79f5e8277d148c26804c85c2c6a399a

**MacBook Pro Early 2015**

- Intel i5 (unknown model, possibly i5 5257U) @ 2.7 GHz
- 8 GB RAM @ 1867 MHz. (DDR3)
- Timings: https://gist.github.com/oliverdunk/ad3dd134b653c43c9928

Code https://github.com/oliverdunk/Polydivisbles

Comment: How much memory have you allowed the Java VM

Comment: I have allowed 8192m(-Xmx 8192m)

Comment: Same version of Java on both machines?  Same amount of memory assigned to the Java VM?

Comment: I assume they have less, however I just realised my target version was 1.7, not 1.8. It didn't make a difference with timings though.

Comment: How many threads are being used on each machine?

Comment: I don't know, I assume theyre at default on each. In task manager each thread goes to 100% on my windows computer

Comment: I cannot answer your question if you cannot tell me how many threads your Java application is using on each machine

Comment: How would I find their information?

Comment: On the Windows machine, are you running the program against 32-bit Java on 64-bit Windows?

Comment: Possibly, it was in "Program Files", not "Program Files (x86)".